# why does the directory octave~1.1 appear in my search path

Tags: ide, octave, search-path

Why does my octave file paths have the directory name, `OCTAVE~1.1` in them when I query octave's search path in the IDE?

An example of a path would be `-- C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\lib\octave\site\oct\api-v51\x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the Windows short-name for a folder with more letters than fit in the old DOS 8.3 naming format.

If octave 4.2.1 is installed to C:\Octave\octave-4.2.1, windows will display the full name but often internally use octave~1.1

When octave sets its internal paths, it must see the short name and default to using it.